# How to create a semi transparent window in WPF that allows mouse events to pass through

Tags: wpf, transparency

I am trying to create an effect similar to the Lights out /lights dim feature in Adobe Lightroom (http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=87hNd3vaENE) except in WPF.

What I tried was to create another window over-top of my existing window, make it transparent and put a semi transparent Path geometry on it.  But I want mouse events to be able to pass through this semi transparent window (on to windows below).

This is a simplified version of what I have:

```
<Window x:Class="LightsOut.MaskWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    AllowsTransparency="True" 
    WindowStyle="None"
    ShowInTaskbar="False"
    Topmost="True" 
    Background="Transparent">

<Grid>

    <Button HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="20" Width="60">click</Button>

    <Path IsHitTestVisible="False" Stroke="Black" Fill="Black" Opacity="0.3">

        <Path.Data>
            <RectangleGeometry Rect="0,0,1000,1000 "/>
        </Path.Data>
    </Path>             

</Grid>
```

The window is fully transparent, so on places where the Path doesn't cover, mouse events pass right through.  So far so good.  The IsHitTestvisible  is set to false on the path object.  So mouse events will pass through it to other controls on the same form (ie you can click on the Button, because it is on the same form).

But mouse events wont pass through the Path object onto windows that are below it.

Any ideas?  Or better ways to solve this problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

I've had similar problem and found a solution:

```
public static class WindowsServices
{
  const int WS_EX_TRANSPARENT = 0x00000020;
  const int GWL_EXSTYLE = (-20);

  [DllImport("user32.dll")]
  static extern int GetWindowLong(IntPtr hwnd, int index);

  [DllImport("user32.dll")]
  static extern int SetWindowLong(IntPtr hwnd, int index, int newStyle);

  public static void SetWindowExTransparent(IntPtr hwnd)
  {
    var extendedStyle = GetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_EXSTYLE);
    SetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_EXSTYLE, extendedStyle | WS_EX_TRANSPARENT);
  }
}
```

for your window set:

```
WindowStyle = None
Topmost = true
AllowsTransparency = true
```

in code behind for the window add:

```
protected override void OnSourceInitialized(EventArgs e)
{
  base.OnSourceInitialized(e);
  var hwnd = new WindowInteropHelper(this).Handle;
  WindowsServices.SetWindowExTransparent(hwnd);
}
```

and voila - click-through window! See original answer in: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/a3cb7db6-5014-430f-a5c2-c9746b077d4f

Comment: this is awesome, I would just like to accomplish one more thing: hiding the cursor. basically setting the Cursor to None, but with this COOOOL code in place the Cursor changes based on what is underneath the window. Is there any way to make the clicks fall through our window AND not have the cursor visible?

Comment: works perfectly! I was able to use your "click through" method on WPF window in WinForms application.

Comment: Unfortunately, by doing so, the button looks unclickable now.

Answer (score 2):

What you described sounds like the expected behavior. One solution is to set the Fill to {x:Null} on the Path as that is the only sure way to make an object not hit test.

Comment: And where goes the **semi** transparency?

Answer (score 1):

I haveanother idea.

What if you made exactly ONE PIXEL, right under the mouse cursor, completely transparent? :]