# Window Hud Behavior (Pass through clicks, can't be minimized)

Tags: c#, wpf, window, label, hud

I'd like to write a simple HUD style application using WPF (if I'm using the wrong technology, I'll take suggestions).

As a simple example, I'd to place text along the top of the screen like "Library Computer" that ignores all clicks (ie doesn't effect the rest of Windows) but is always on top and can't be minimized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Relevant properties to set on the window:

- [`AllowsTranparency`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.allowstransparency.aspx) -> `true`
- [`WindowStyle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.windowstyle.aspx) -> `None`
- [`ResizeMode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.resizemode.aspx) -> `NoResize`
- [`WindowState`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.windowstate.aspx) -> `Maximized`
- [`Topmost`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.topmost.aspx) -> `true`
- [`IsHitTestVisible`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.ishittestvisible.aspx) -> `false` (This alone won't do, you need some [OS interop](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2842667/546730))

Comment: Great tips! I also added ShowInTaskbar="False" which gets me my desired effect *except* as soon as I click anything else, it goes behind. :/

Comment: Really? Hmm. I put some task on top of the task bar and it looked fine but when I click the task bar it goes behind (I can see it blurred out behind the aero task bar).

Comment: @Ternary: You are right, some windows components seem to ignore it, you might need to look for a more low level approach than WPF windows...

Comment: @Ternary: By the way, do you get clicks to pass through? If not see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2842667/546730).

Comment: Thanks! That definitely works to allow the cursor to go "through" the text. Now if I can just prevent the window from losing focus and going into the background I think I'm set!