# Force WinForm Application on top Windows 10 Tablet Mode

Tags: winforms, windows-10, tablet, tablet-pc

Is there any way to force a simple winforms application to run on top the tablet mode main screen ?

It can be Vb script or anything, the idea is to show a count down application on top the main screen to announce the upcoming "force shutdown" of that tablet.

[screnshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rwQSF.png)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24009579/put-a-semi-transparent-mark-on-screen-windows-xp this might help

Comment: @EpicKip thank you! it wasn't what I was looking for but certainly making things better for my second need!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whoever face the same problem, there is a "hack" I was reading about.

When on tablet mode, your application will be start as "minimized" in the taskbar, therefore you will not be able to see it, just a "Home screen".

What worked for me was adding to my `Form_Load` event the `SendKey` Function, with <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>tab</kbd>.
That, mixing with @EpicKip answer just above, will always send the app (even when on start screen of "Tablet Mode" and the app on "Minimized").

```
private void form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  //SetWindowPos(this.Handle, HWND_TOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0, TOPMOST_FLAGS);

  Thread.Sleep(1000);
  SendKeys.SendWait("%{TAB}");
}
```