# Allow mouse events to pass through semitransparent Popup

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, popup, wpf-controls

I'm trying to do a drag-n-drop operation from a control inside a `Popup`. The content being dragged will be placed at the position of the drop so when the drag starts I want to make the `Popup` semitransparent to allow placement under it. But so far I fail to make mouse events pass through my semitransparent `Popup`.

The following xaml works fine, the `Button` is still clickable when hovering the `Rectangle` with the mouse

```
<Grid>
    <Rectangle Panel.ZIndex="2"
               Width="200"
               Height="200"
               Fill="Green"
               IsHitTestVisible="False"
               Opacity="0.5"/>
    <Button Content="Click Me"
            FontSize="22"
            FontWeight="Bold"/>
</Grid>
```

[image]

But the following xaml fails to allow mouse event to pass through when the mouse hovers the `Rectangle` inside the `Popup`.

```
<Grid>
    <Popup Placement="Center"
           AllowsTransparency="True"
           IsHitTestVisible="False"
           IsOpen="True">
        <Rectangle Width="100"
                   Height="50"
                   Fill="Green"
                   IsHitTestVisible="False"
                   Opacity="0.5"/>
    </Popup>
    <Button Content="Click Me"
            FontSize="22"
            FontWeight="Bold"/>
</Grid>
```

[image]

I've tried to get the `PopupRoot` top parent of the `Rectangle` and set both `IsHitTestVisible` and `Opacity` for every element in the visual tree explicitly but it still doesn't work. The only way I can sort of get it to work is by setting `Background`/`Fill` to `Transparent` but it looks weird and hovering the parts that aren't `Transparent` still fails.

I've read the following link but as far as I can tell, that will only work for a `Window` and not a `Popup`.
[How to create a semi transparent window in WPF that allows mouse events to pass through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2842667/how-to-create-a-semi-transparent-window-in-wpf-that-allows-mouse-events-to-pass)

Does anyone have any solutions or suggestions? :-)

Comment: In my humble opinion, this is either a bug in WPF or the documentation of [IsHitTestVisible](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.ishittestvisible%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is wrong or incomplete. I suggest you file a bug report on [Microsoft Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio).

Comment: @NETscape: I would like to try it but I'm not sure how to get a hold of the `Window`. All I can find with snoop is `PopupRoot` which derives from `FrameworkElement` and not `Window`. Got any suggestions on how to find the `Window`?

Comment: @NETscape: I managed to get a hold of the actual `Window` and you were right, it worked :-) Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to the comment made by @NETscape I tried to get a hold of the actual `Window` for the `Popup`. It works with the following code (after the `Popup` is initially shown I might add..)

```
// FromVisual can take any Visual inside the Popup..
HwndSource popupHwndSource = HwndSource.FromVisual(rectangle) as HwndSource;
```

Combining this with the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2842667/how-to-create-a-semi-transparent-window-in-wpf-that-allows-mouse-events-to-pass) I created an attached behavior which adds the property `IsPopupEventTransparent` which can be set on any child in the `Popup`. At first, this solution caused a bug which forced the users to click twice to re-activate the `Window` after the `Popup` lost its event transparency. I solved this with a "`Mouse.Capture`-workaround".

```
elementInPopup.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
{
    Keyboard.Focus(elementInPopup);
    Mouse.Capture(elementInPopup);
    elementInPopup.ReleaseMouseCapture();
}));
```

Usable like this

```
<Popup AllowsTransparency="True"
       ...>
    <Border inf:PopupBehavior.IsPopupEventTransparent="{Binding SomeProperty}"
            BorderThickness="1"
            BorderBrush="Black"
            Background="White"
            Margin="0 0 8 8">
        <Border.Effect>
            <DropShadowEffect ShadowDepth="2.25" 
                              Color="Black"
                              Opacity="0.4"
                              Direction="315"
                              BlurRadius="4"/>
        </Border.Effect>
        <!--...-->
    </Border>
</Popup>
```

**PopupBehavior**

```
public class PopupBehavior
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsPopupEventTransparentProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("IsPopupEventTransparent",
                                            typeof(bool),
                                            typeof(PopupBehavior),
                                            new UIPropertyMetadata(false, OnIsPopupEventTransparentPropertyChanged));

    public static bool GetIsPopupEventTransparent(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (bool)obj.GetValue(IsPopupEventTransparentProperty);
    }
    public static void SetIsPopupEventTransparent(DependencyObject obj, bool value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(IsPopupEventTransparentProperty, value);
    }
    private static void OnIsPopupEventTransparentPropertyChanged(DependencyObject target, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        FrameworkElement element = target as FrameworkElement;
        if ((bool)e.NewValue == true)
        {
            FrameworkElement topParent = VisualTreeHelpers.GetTopParent(element) as FrameworkElement;
            topParent.Opacity = 0.4;
            HwndSource popupHwndSource = HwndSource.FromVisual(element) as HwndSource;
            WindowHelper.SetWindowExTransparent(popupHwndSource.Handle);
        }
        else
        {
            FrameworkElement topParent = VisualTreeHelpers.GetTopParent(element) as FrameworkElement;
            topParent.Opacity = 1.0;
            HwndSource popupHwndSource = HwndSource.FromVisual(element) as HwndSource;
            WindowHelper.UndoWindowExTransparent(popupHwndSource.Handle, element);
        }
    }
}
```

**WindowHelper** *based on the answer to this [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2842667/how-to-create-a-semi-transparent-window-in-wpf-that-allows-mouse-events-to-pass)*

```
public static class WindowHelper
{
    private static Dictionary<IntPtr, int> _extendedStyleHwndDictionary = new Dictionary<IntPtr, int>();

    const int WS_EX_TRANSPARENT = 0x00000020;
    const int GWL_EXSTYLE = (-20);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern int GetWindowLong(IntPtr hwnd, int index);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern int SetWindowLong(IntPtr hwnd, int index, int newStyle);

    public static void SetWindowExTransparent(IntPtr hwnd)
    {
        int extendedStyle = GetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_EXSTYLE);
        SetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_EXSTYLE, extendedStyle | WS_EX_TRANSPARENT);
        if (_extendedStyleHwndDictionary.Keys.Contains(hwnd) == false)
        {
            _extendedStyleHwndDictionary.Add(hwnd, extendedStyle);
        }
    }

    public static void UndoWindowExTransparent(IntPtr hwnd, FrameworkElement elementInPopup)
    {
        if (_extendedStyleHwndDictionary.Keys.Contains(hwnd) == true)
        {
            int extendedStyle = _extendedStyleHwndDictionary[hwnd];
            SetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_EXSTYLE, extendedStyle);
            // Fix Focus problems that forces the users to click twice to
            // re-activate the window after the Popup loses event transparency
            elementInPopup.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
            {
                Keyboard.Focus(elementInPopup);
                Mouse.Capture(elementInPopup);
                elementInPopup.ReleaseMouseCapture();
            }));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is not with popup but issue is with the color `Green` when applied to the rectangle this effectively blocks the mouse event to pass through

try the sample below with transparent background, I placed a border to show the presence

```
<Grid>
    <Popup Placement="Center"
           AllowsTransparency="True"
           IsHitTestVisible="False"
           IsOpen="True">
        <Border Width="100"
                Height="50"
                Background="Transparent"
                BorderBrush="Black"
                BorderThickness="4"
                IsHitTestVisible="False"
                Opacity="0.5" />
    </Popup>
    <Button Content="Click Me"
            FontSize="22"
            FontWeight="Bold" />
</Grid>
```

so any color having `non zero alpha` component will block the mouse events

refer to below for alpha example

- #FF00FF00 Green `Fail`
- #9900FF00 semi transparent Green `Fail`
- #0100FF00 almost invisible Green `Fail`
- #0000FF00 full transparent Green `Pass`

so you need to have transparent color in order for mouse event to be passed through

Since popup is a generated as a layered window on top of the app window, so if you need a background you may need to implement the how to create the semi transparent window solution. there seems to be no built solution in wpf

Comment: This is similar to what I wrote in the end of the question, setting `Background`/`Fill` to `Transparent` sort of works but it still fails if you hover the borderlines (`BorderThickness="4"`). And yes, I'm considering a `Window` as an alternate solution. Thanks :-)