# Making PART of a WPF window click-through, but not its controls

Tags: wpf, user-interface, background, transparent, click-through

In order to achieve a dropshadow effect, my window is slighty bigger than its main content with a transparent "border" around it. I am curious if there's a possibility to make this invisible border (coloured part in image) click-through only and prevent main content from being click-through.

[image]

This thread explains what to do in order to make the whole window click-through:
[Making a WPF window click-through, but not its controls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34510416/making-a-wpf-window-click-through-but-not-its-controls)

Is there any way to adapt this approach for what I intend do achieve?

Answer (score 0):

Only a window with a fully transparent background is really click through. For a semi-transparent window you could for example minimize the window yourself when clicking on the shadow, e.g.:

```
private void Grid_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.OriginalSource == outer)
        WindowState = WindowState.Minimized;
}
```

**XAML:**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="300" Width="300"
        AllowsTransparency="True" WindowStyle="None">
    <Window.Background>
        <SolidColorBrush Color="Red" Opacity="0.3" />
    </Window.Background>
    <Grid x:Name="outer" Background="Transparent" MouseLeftButtonDown="Grid_MouseLeftButtonDown">
        <Grid Background="Silver" Margin="10">
            <TextBlock>GUI</TextBlock>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: I have thought about this solution as well, but in case window is shown on top of desktop only, it will minimise as well although it usually wouldn't.

Is there a way to determine the window shown below and focus this one instead of minimising?