# Qt5, transparent window and wheel events

Tags: c++, qt, winapi, transparent, mousewheel

I have a simplest test case application:

TransWidget.cpp:

```
TransWidget::TransWidget(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent, Qt::Window | Qt::FramelessWindowHint)
{
    setAttribute(Qt::WA_ShowWithoutActivating);
    setAttribute(Qt::WA_TransparentForMouseEvents);
    setAttribute(Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground);
}

void TransWidget::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *)
{
    // some code to mark the presence of the window
}

void TransWidget::wheelEvent(QWheelEvent * ev)
{
    ev->ignore(); // keeps getting here no matter what I try!
}
```

main.cpp:

```
#include "TransWidget.h"
#include "OpaqueWidget.h"

#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    OpaqueWidget o;
    auto t = new TransWidget(&o);

    o.show();
    t->show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Opaque widget simply reports when it gets mouse clicks and wheel events. Transparent widget overlays the opaque widget.

Mouse clicks work as expected:

- fall through transparent regions to the opaque widget;
- get caught by transparent widget when clicked in its painted (thus opaque) areas.

Wheel events get caught by the transparent widget no matter where they occur.
The same setup used to work with Qt4.8. Is it a bug in Qt5? Any workarounds possible?

The solution to a similar question doesn't seem to work also:
[How to create a semi transparent window in WPF that allows mouse events to pass through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2842667/how-to-create-a-semi-transparent-window-in-wpf-that-allows-mouse-events-to-pass)

(Qt 5.6.1, Windows 10)

Comment: Windows 10 changed a lot. Have you tried turning *Settings* -> *Devices* -> *Mouse & touchpad*: *Scroll inactive windows when I hover over them* off? Not an answer to your question, but something to narrow down what's causing this.

Comment: @IInspectable Wow, didn't know about this setting) But toggling it doesn't change the behaviour...

Comment: Have you checked that it doesn't have the `Qt::WheelFocus` flag set for its focus policy? This is unlikely, but it's the only thing I can think of.

Comment: Btw, as a workaround, install an event filter for `QWheelEvent`.

Comment: @JonHarper Checked now, it's Qt::NoFocus. Sigh...

Comment: Open a bug report?

Comment: @JonHarper Likely so, if it stays unanswered for the next few hours...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accepted as a Qt bug, see https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-53418 for details.