# How can I make the button clickable on a semi-transparent path geometry which passes all mouse events through?

Tags: c#, wpf, winapi

I need to control behind semi-transparent background with mouse.
In detail, my app fills up the whole screen with semi-transparent background and it has got a button on it.
I wanted to be able to click on any parts behind the semi-transparent background and the solution for this I found is this:
[How to create a semi transparent window in WPF that allows mouse events to pass through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2842667/how-to-create-a-semi-transparent-window-in-wpf-that-allows-mouse-events-to-pass)

With this solution, I was able to click and do everything with mouse behind the background but unfortunately, I cannot click on that button anymore because the button also passed the mouse events through itself.

How can I make the button clickable?
Any help would be appreciated.
You can try the example app on the provided link above.
Thanks

Comment: Maybe you can set the e.IsHandled in the click-event of your window to false

Comment: You can check MouseOver event and when it's over the button - remove WS_EX_TRANSPARENT style.

Comment: hi, Do you try using keyboard messages to control behind semi-transparent background?

Comment: @montonero, It might work but how can I do that? Please let me know if you've already encountered such a problem and solved it

Comment: @Strive Sun - MSFT, I am not sure about keyboard events but mouse events for sure

Comment: @DenisSchaf, Could you show me how to do it in detail? Thanks

Comment: in this case you would have to provide your XAML code so we can see whats actually happening

Comment: @Jay I used such approach for a usual Win32 application, not WPF. But I believe this shouldn't be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the problem myself.
The solution was mouse hook.
Perhaps, @montonero's idea is right.
When mouse is over the desired region, I removed WS_EX_TRANSPARENT.