# How to create a semi transparent overlay with clickable controls

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, winforms, xaml

I want to create a semi-transparent window (black with some opacity) with some controls (maybe one + and - to increase/decrease opacity). I am using WPF and have looked at the following stackoverflow answers

[How can I make an "overlay" window that allows mouse clicks to pass through to windows below it, but still allow some controls to be clicked?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58824122/how-can-i-make-an-overlay-window-that-allows-mouse-clicks-to-pass-through-to-w)

This works as long as intended only when the window is fully transparent, adding some opacity breaks the overlay behavior

[How to create a semi transparent window in WPF that allows mouse events to pass through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2842667/how-to-create-a-semi-transparent-window-in-wpf-that-allows-mouse-events-to-pass/3367137#3367137)

With this approach, I lose the click functionality of the controls.

How do I combine these both? I can change to other framework like winforms, winui if that would make things easier

Answer (score 0):

According to [WS_EX_TRANSPARENT explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6165188/10706024)

> WS_EX_TRANSPARENT makes your events (like mouse clicks) fall through your window, amongst other things. Opacity is a separate concept, it instructs window manager to apply alphablending when drawing your form.

So, if I understand your question correct, you want to have a `Transparent Window` that allows to click objects that are underneath it, but also have controls on that Window that are also clickable.

In order to do so, you need to find a compromise.

Because when you apply `WS_EX_TRANSPARENT` it's simply no longer clickable, so in order to *come back* to normal Window, you need to somehow trigger a method to reset `WS_EX_TRANSPARENT`.

I've created an example in .NET6 and WPF, where I toggle `WS_EX_TRANSPARENT`, on `PreviewKeyDown` event.
It's of course necessary, Window to be focused when trying to reset `WS_EX_TRANSPARENT` on this example.

### XAML

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp8.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp8"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        Title="MainWindow"
        Width="300"
        Height="300"
        WindowStyle="None"
        AllowsTransparency="True"
        Topmost="True"
        BorderThickness="5"
        BorderBrush="LimeGreen"
        Background="Transparent"
        PreviewKeyDown="Window_PreviewKeyDown"
        mc:Ignorable="d">

    <DockPanel>
        <Border Height="40"
                DockPanel.Dock="Top"
                Background="Blue"
                MouseDown="Border_MouseDown"/>

        <Button x:Name="button"
                Grid.Row="2"
                Width="75"
                Height="50"
                Margin="10"
                DockPanel.Dock="Bottom"
                Content="Button"
                Click="button_Click"/>

        <Border Background="Black" Opacity="0.5"/>
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

### CodeBehind

```
namespace WpfApp8
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private bool _borderClicked;

        private IntPtr _handle;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override void OnSourceInitialized(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnSourceInitialized(e);
            _handle = new WindowInteropHelper(this).Handle;
            WindowsServices.SetWindowExNormal(_handle);
        }

        private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.BorderBrush = !_borderClicked ? new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red) : new SolidColorBrush(Colors.LimeGreen);
            _borderClicked = !_borderClicked;
        }

        private void Window_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Key == Key.D1 && (Keyboard.Modifiers & ModifierKeys.Control) == ModifierKeys.Control)
            {
                WindowsServices.SetWindowExNormal(_handle);
            }
            else if (e.Key == Key.D2 && (Keyboard.Modifiers & ModifierKeys.Control) == ModifierKeys.Control)
            {
                WindowsServices.SetWindowExTransparent(_handle);
            }
        }

        private void Border_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            // Drag window
            this.DragMove();
        }
    }

    public static class WindowsServices
    {
        const int WS_EX_TRANSPARENT = 0x00000020;
        const int GWL_EXSTYLE = (-20);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern int GetWindowLong(IntPtr hwnd, int index);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern int SetWindowLong(IntPtr hwnd, int index, int newStyle);

        public static void SetWindowExTransparent(IntPtr hwnd)
        {
            var extendedStyle = GetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_EXSTYLE);
            SetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_EXSTYLE, extendedStyle | WS_EX_TRANSPARENT);
        }

        public static void SetWindowExNormal(IntPtr hwnd)
        {
            int extendedStyle = GetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_EXSTYLE);
            SetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_EXSTYLE, extendedStyle & ~WS_EX_TRANSPARENT);
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Example]